# Vaadin @PWA annotation not recognized

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, vaadin14

I'm working with Vaadin 14 and Springboot. I want to make a PWA, but @PWA annotation is simply not working as expected.  I defined it in the Application.java:

```
@PWA(name = "Long name",
    shortName = "Name",
    offlinePath="offline.html",
    offlineResources = "./images/icon.png",
    description = "description")
```

But the install prompt does not appear. I cheked the Application tab in the DevTools, but neither the service worker nor the manifest is created.

I have made other PWAs previously, but this never happened... I don't know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser needs to access it from an HTTPS link. If you're on localhost, you can simulate this by going to `chrome://flags/` search `Insecure origins treated as secure` and enter the url. For example:

[image: screenshot for chrome flags1]

Comment: I tried what you suggested but "unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure" flag is not working. Indeed, the browser alerts that it is not allowed since it affects security. However, I never had to do such thing in order to make it work as expected...

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I wasn't...

Comment: Do you get this error: `TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8080/') with script ('http://localhost:8080/sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.` ? from the small Vaadin icon on the bottom right?

Comment: Also, prior Vaadin 14 apps had a "prompt" property in the PWA annotation but it was removed. That may be why you could get it to work before.

Comment: Not at all, there is no problem in running the application and no error appears. The unique problem is that the install prompt does not appear. It is true that PWA annotation has "enableInstallPrompt" prompt, but it has true as it's default value, and there is no change in adding it